# org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Header section has more than 10240 bytes

Tags: java, html, grails

I have in my file

```
<g:form accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myFormScenario" url="[action:'save',controller:'test']">
  <input type="hidden" name="test" ng-model="test" />
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</g:form>
```

If "test" value are 10 000 characters => it's work), but

if "test" value are 22 0000 caracteres = dont work when i click in submit

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Header section has more than 10240 bytes (maybe it is not properly terminated)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:362)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:158)
... 63 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Header section has more than 10240 bytes (maybe it is not properly terminated)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.readHeaders(MultipartStream.java:543)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:1038)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.hasNext(FileUploadBase.java:1106)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:339)
... 65 more
```